# Change height of toolbar material design

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

How can I changed the height of md-toolbar in material design?

[http://jsfiddle.net/kostonstyle/gsroofa5/](http://jsfiddle.net/g8z57Lvz/1/)

On the first toolbar I want a height from 30px and tried that:

```
<md-toolbar style:"height: 30px;">
```

But it does not work at all. I need a navbar with two bulks, that because of two toolbar.

I try this, but now letter disappear.

http://jsfiddle.net/kostonstyle/r178sp9o/1/

Comment: Here is a working link :    https://jsfiddle.net/r178sp9o/12/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The height of the toolbar can be changed by adding the classes to the `md-toolbar`.

For a medium sized toolbar add `class="md-medium-tall"`

For toolbar bigger than the normal add `class="md-tall"`

You can also inline style the toolbar `style="height:50px;"`

Comment: I want smaller toolbar than default, and its not working

Answer (score 17):

You can use an inline style like this

```
<md-toolbar style="min-height:30px">
```

Use **min-height** to make the toolbar smaller

Comment: Depending on how your page is set up, this may not work. I added my workaround below (works in some cases where only setting the `min-height` doesn't work)

Comment: Thank you! This was the missing piece of not being able to scale the md-toolbar smaller than 64px

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer did not work for me. Here is how I got it working in my Angular Material app:

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary"
     style="min-height: 30px !important; height: 30px !important;">
```

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me on Angular 8. Put this code in your scss

```
.mat-toolbar {
  min-height: 50px !important; 
  height: 50px !important;
}

.mat-toolbar-row {
  min-height: 50px !important; 
  height: 50px !important;
}
```

Replace 'mat' with 'md'

Answer (score 3):

If just setting the `min-height` doesn't work, like it didn't work for me, you will also have to add in `max-height` with the same value:

HTML

```
<md-toolbar class="toolbar"></md-toolbar>
```

CSS

```
.toolbar {
  max-height: 30px;
  min-height: 30px;
}
```